# How to Generate Python Bindings for Thrift in Bazel

Tags: python, code-generation, thrift, bazel

I'm attempting to generate Python bindings for a Thrift service definition  using Bazel.  As far as I've been able to tell, there is no existing `.bzl` for doing this so I'm somewhat on my own here.  I've written `.bzl` rules in the past but the situation I'm running into in this case is different.

The general issue is that I don't know the names of the output files from the `thrift` command before the build starts which means that I can't generate a `py_library` rule with a `srcs` attribute set correctly since I don't have the names of the files.  I've tried to follow examples whereby the output files are known ahead of time by way of generating a `.zip` file, but the `py_library` rule only allows `.py` files as srcs so this doesn't work.

The only thing I can think of would be to use a `repository_rule` to generate the code and `BUILD` files but what I'm trying to accomplish doesn't seem like much of a stretch and should be supported.

Comment: Hey Bryan, I'm stuck in a similar situation. I asked something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65672680/2932244) Could you share on what was your final approach?

Answer (score 0):

Someone has attempted this before.

Discussion here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/bazel-dev/g3DVmhVhNZs

Code Here:
https://github.com/wt/bazel_thrift

I would start there.

Edit:
I started there. I did not get as far as I hoped. Bazel is being extended to support having multiple outputs generated by one input, but it does not allow that very easily just yet, per:

> groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/bazel-discuss/3WQhHm194yU

Regardless, I did attempt something for C++ thrift bindings, which have the same issue. The Java example got around this by using the source jar as a build source, which won't work for us. To make it work, I passed in the list of source files I cared about that would be created by the thrift generator. I then reported these files as the output that would be generated in the impl. That seems to work. It is a bit nasty in that you have to know what files you are looking for before you build, but it does work. It would also be possible to have a small program read the thift file and determine the output files it would make. That would be nicer, but I don't have the time. Plus, the current approach is nice, in that it explicitly defines what files you are looking for thrift to generate, which makes the BUILD file a little bit easier to understand for a newbie like me.

First pass at some code, maybe I will clean it up and submit it as a patch (maybe not):

```
###########
# CPP gen 
###########

# Create Generated cpp source files from thrift idl files.
# 
def _gen_thrift_cc_src_impl(ctx):
    out = ctx.outputs.outs

    if not out:
        # empty set
        # nothing to do, no inputs to build
        return DefaultInfo(files=depset(out))

    # Used dir(out[0]) to see what
    # we had available in the object. 
    # dirname attribute tells us the directory
    # we should be putting stuff in, works nicely.
    # ctx.genfile_dir is not the output directory
    # when called as an external repository
    target_genfiles_root = out[0].dirname 
    thrift_includes_root = "/".join(
        [ target_genfiles_root, "thrift_includes"])
    gen_cpp_dir = "/".join([target_genfiles_root,"." ])

    commands = []

    commands.append(_mkdir_command_string(target_genfiles_root))
    commands.append(_mkdir_command_string(thrift_includes_root))

    thrift_lib_archive_files = ctx.attr.thrift_library._transitive_archive_files
    for f in thrift_lib_archive_files:
        commands.append(
            _tar_extract_command_string(f.path, thrift_includes_root))

    commands.append(_mkdir_command_string(gen_cpp_dir))
    thrift_lib_srcs = ctx.attr.thrift_library.srcs
    for src in thrift_lib_srcs:
        commands.append(_thrift_cc_compile_command_string(
            thrift_includes_root, gen_cpp_dir, src))


    inputs = (
        list(thrift_lib_archive_files) + thrift_lib_srcs )

    ctx.action(
        inputs = inputs,
        outputs = out,
        progress_message = "Generating CPP sources from thift archive %s" % target_genfiles_root,
        command = " && ".join(commands),
    )
    return DefaultInfo(files=depset(out))


thrift_cc_gen_src=  rule(
    _gen_thrift_cc_src_impl,
        attrs = {
            "thrift_library": attr.label(
                mandatory=True, providers=['srcs', '_transitive_archive_files']),
            "outs" : attr.output_list(mandatory=True, non_empty=True),
        },output_to_genfiles = True,
    )

# wraps cc_library to generate a library from one or more .thrift files
#   provided as a thrift_library bundle.
# 
# Generates all src and hdr files needed, but you must specify the expected
# files. This is a bug in bazel: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/bazel-discuss/3WQhHm194yU
# 
# Instead of src and hdrs, requires: cpp_srcs and cpp_hdrs. These are required.
#
# Takes:
#           name: The library name, like cc_library
#  
# thrift_library: The library of source .thrift files from which our
#                 code will be built from.
# 
#       cpp_srcs: The expected source that will be generated and built. Passed to
#                 cc_library as src.
#
#       cpp_hdrs: The expected header files that will be generated. Passed to 
#                 cc_library as hdrs.
#
# Rest of options are documented in native.cc_library 
#

def thrift_cc_library(name, thrift_library, 
                      cpp_srcs=[],cpp_hdrs=[],
                      build_skeletons=False,
                      deps=[], alwayslink=0, copts=[], 
                      defines=[], include_prefix=None, 
                      includes=[], linkopts=[], 
                      linkstatic=0, nocopts=None,
                      strip_include_prefix=None,
                      textual_hdrs=[],
                      visibility=None):
    # from our thrift_library tarball source bundle, 
    # create a generated cpp source directory.
    outs = []
    for src in cpp_srcs:
        outs.append("//:"+src)
    for hdr in cpp_hdrs:    
        outs.append("//:"+hdr)
    thrift_cc_gen_src( 
        name = name + 'cc_gen_src',
        thrift_library = thrift_library,
        outs = outs,
    )

    # Then make the library for the given name.
    native.cc_library(
        name = name,
        deps = deps,
        srcs = cpp_srcs,
        hdrs = cpp_hdrs,
        alwayslink = alwayslink,
        copts = copts,
        defines=defines,
        include_prefix=include_prefix,
        includes=includes,
        linkopts=linkopts,
        linkstatic=linkstatic,
        nocopts=nocopts,
        strip_include_prefix=strip_include_prefix,
        textual_hdrs=textual_hdrs,
        visibility=visibility,
    )
```

Comment: Yes, I'd thought about just explicitly stating the files that should be generated.  It's gross so I didn't go down that path despite the fact that I know it would work.  I'd thought, too, about using a repository rule but that seemed fraught.  Lastly, I'd thought about generating a `.zip` of the generated files and building a stub `.py` that unpacks the `.zip` containing the sources.  I'm sure it would work but again, this seems like a hack.