# How to package generated python files in custom Bazel rule or genrule?

Tags: python, bazel, bazel-rules

Let's say I have a scripts which generates Java and Python code. The files it generates depends on the input config, it can vary based on the config. Now, in the case of Java, I can write a simple genrule, point to invoke the script and then call `jar` command to generate a single source package of the generated Python files.

Eg:

```
genrule(
    name = "generated_java_srcjar",
    srcs = glob([
        ":input-files"
    ]),
    outs = [
        "xsd.srcjar"
    ],
    cmd = """
        mkdir -p $(GENDIR)/generated-code
        $(location path/to/custom/script) --output-directory $(GENDIR)/generated-code --input $(locations :input-files)
        $(JAVABASE)/bin/jar cMf $@ -C $(GENDIR)/generated-code .
    """,
)

java_library(
    name = "generated_java_jar",
    srcs = [
        ":generated_java_srcjar"
    ],
)
```

In the Java example, to declare an output for the genrule, I'm able to generate a single output (source package of the generated files) and then use the same rule as a source in the `java_library` rule.

Now, I want to achieve something similar in Python. How can I package the generated Python files after invoking the custom script so that I can then pass it as a source to `py_library` rule?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to write your own Starlark rule that returns a [PyInfo provider](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/PyInfo.html) with your generated files in the `transitive_sources`. You'd then add the rule to the `deps` attribute of your py_library rule.

The drawback is that you have to know at [loading phase](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/glossary.html#target-graph) (so before the code generation has happened) what files will be generated by your tool, no cheating with zips/jars.

If that's not an option I could think of a hacky workaround where you produce a zip that you depend on in your py_libarary's data deps. You then unpack the file at runtime before you actually import it.

Depending on how you've set up your python rules you might also be able to build a python wheel in your code generator and depend on that.